# Is there a way to get the list of struct output of value_counts polars into a json?

Tags: json, dataframe, python-polars, word-count

I'm starting with Polars and I'm trying to word count a list of strings in polars and get the results as a dict into a polars dataframe.

Basically, I have this input dataframe:

```
df_test = pl.DataFrame({'a': [['the', 'dog', 'is', 'good', 'a'], ['toto', 'tata', 'I']]})
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────────────────┐
│ a                     │
│ ---                   │
│ list[str]             │
╞═══════════════════════╡
│ ["the", "dog", … "a"] │
│ ["toto", "tata", "I"] │
└───────────────────────┘
```

from the command:

```
df_test.with_columns(
    pl.col('a').arr.eval(pl.element().value_counts())
)
```

I get this output:

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                 │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"is",1}, {"dog",1}, … {"good",… │
│ [{"tata",1}, {"I",1}, {"toto",1}… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is there a way to get the result of value_counts like this?

[image]

Thanks by advance

Comment: It's better if you can provide the outputs as text instead of (or along with) screenshots. I've done the first two as an example - maybe you can fix the last one?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `value_counts` output to a string, do some operations on each string (remove all `{}`, replace `,` with `:`), `arr.join` the list into one big string, then add back the final `{}` with [`pl.format`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.format.html#polars.format):

```py
df_test.with_columns(
        a=pl.format(
            "{{}}",
            pl.col("a")
            .arr.eval(
                pl.element()
                .value_counts()
                .cast(str)
                .str.strip("{}")
                .str.replace(",", ": ")
            )
            .arr.join(", "),
        )
    )
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                                │
│ ---                                              │
│ str                                              │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"good": 1, "dog": 1, "a": 1, "is": 1, "the": 1} │
│ {"tata": 1, "toto": 1, "I": 1}                   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This works as long as no words have a `,`, which for a word count seems like a safe assumption. I think there's a potentially more general answer with using `pl.format` within `arr.eval`, but I got errors when trying to use `struct` expressions as arguments to `pl.format` within that context.

Comment: Thanks @Wayoshi for your answer ! But it seems that it's not possible to cast a struct into a string: I'm getting this error when i tried to reproduce your solution ArrowErrorException: NotYetImplemented("Cannot cast from struct to other types"). I'm using the latest version of polars == 0.17.2

Comment: @dams The latest version is `0.17.12`. I think a feature to cast struct was added since then. I just tried the code again on my end and it works.